# SQL Query - Partition by

Tags: sql, window-functions, row-number

From below table, need to fetch all records in green. For each group partitioned by `sfdc_acc` column, retrieve the latest record on the basis of status. In case if status is Available or NotAvailable in one partition, need to retrieve the latest record with Available.

[image: Table]

This query is not returning the proper result as expected:

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TEMP.*,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ERP_ACC 
                             ORDER BY LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC, STATUS ASC) AS RN 
     FROM 
         TEMP) A 
WHERE 
    A.RN = 1
```

How should I modify the query to include status check in partition clause?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I would think his syntax suggests that this is TSQL

Comment: what happens if there's only NotAvailable in one group? do you still return the record? or do you just need all the "Available" status?

Comment: @TheIntegrator: Why? All modern DBMS support window functions. SQL Server isn't the only one (and wasn't the first one either)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply filter for `Available` records only.

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(
    SELECT TEMP.*,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ERP_ACC ORDER BY LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC) AS RN FROM TEMP
    where STATUS = 'Available'
) A WHERE A.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ERP_ACC, STATUS ORDER BY LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC) AS RN
      FROM TEMP T
     ) T
WHERE STATUS = 'Available' AND T.RN = 1;
```

Comment: In some groups, status can be all 'Not Available' then latest Not Available to be retrieved. Also there are chances of NULL in some groups, such groups to be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you only need the available status:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( LASTMODIFIEDDATE DATETIME, ERP_ACC int, sfdc_acc VARCHAR(20), status VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('3/31/2017', 156, 'ABC', 'Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('3/30/2017', 678, 'ABC', 'Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('10/17/2016', 872, 'ABC', 'Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('08/02/2016', 900, 'ABC', 'Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('06/09/2017', 100, 'GHK', 'Not Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('05/01/2017', 456, 'GHK', 'Not Available')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('08/02/2016', 954, 'GHK', 'Available')
```

Updated my answer, notice the condition to set to rank Status. if Available then 1, if not, then 2. this would ensure that all records with status "Available" is the priority.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT LASTMODIFIEDDATE,
        ERP_ACC,
        sfdc_acc,
        status, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY sfdc_acc 
        ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN status = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, 
        LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC) AS RN FROM @Table) A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

Comment: In some groups, status can be all 'Not Available' then latest Not Available to be retrieved. Also there are chances of NULL in some groups, such groups to be eliminated.

Comment: @Math590, updated my asnwer. this should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You need to sort by status first then by timestamp to put 'Available' records first then everything else second.

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TEMP.*,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ERP_ACC 
                             ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Available' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC) AS RN 
     FROM 
         TEMP) A 
WHERE 
    A.RN = 1
```